# How can I put a widget above another widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I would like to overlay a Round view on top of a background View just like in this screenshot below.

[image: Getting like this]

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new Container(
  width: 150.0,
  height: 150.0,
  child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
    new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: Text('Hello'),
    ),
    new Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: (){}),
    )
  ],
  ),
);
}
```

[image: above UI will look like this]

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    /*your_widget_1*/,
    /*your_widget_2*/,
  ],
);
```

Comment: The correct Stack class URL: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 3):

```
             Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      child: Image.network(
                        image,
                        height: 150,
                        width: 100,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child:ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 1,
                        color: Color(0xFF69C86C),
                        child: Text(
                          "Name",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `IndexedStack` if you wish to show only one of the children based on the index.

```dart
IndexedStack(
  index: 0,
  children: [
    FooWidget(), // Visible if index = 0
    BarWidget(), // Visible if index = 1
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### solution 1

can use  [be_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/be_widgets) for overlaying widget as label or badge.
It is similar to stack but has very flexible and badge or label draw over the child widget which helps to ignore the size of overlaying widget.

#### solution 2

You can use  [assorted_layout_widgets](https://github.com/marcglasberg/assorted_layout_widgets) and use `RowSuper` or `ColumnSuper` internal spacing (`innerDistance`) in negative value for overlay